# how to copy folders from a gcp bucket folder into another bucket folder and delete it using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I want to get all folders inside a temp folder in the bucket then move it to the bucket itself and delete the temp folder, for example, if I have `gs://bucketname/mainfolder/temp` and this `temp` folder contains 3 folders like `gs://bucketname/mainfolder/temp/folder1` and `gs://bucketname/mainfolder/temp/folder2` and I want to move `folder` and `folder2` (with their contents) into the `mainfolder` so that they are like this: `gs://bucketname/mainfolder/folder1` and `gs://bucketname/mainfolder/folder2` and delete the temp folder with its contents after copying what I need from it.

I was thinking about listing the folder inside the temp folder using `GoogleCloudStorageHook` and using `list`
for exmaple:

```
hook = GoogleCloudStorageHook()
hook.list(bucket="bucketname", prefix="mainfolder/temp/", delimiter='/')
```

but am not so sure how to proceed after this. any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, folders doesn't exist. Therefore, you must copy files, one by one by changing their name. The name of a file (an object in fact) is the full path from the root of the bucket (because all the objects are put a the bucket level, no folder in a GCS bucket).

So, you can filter by a prefix all the objects, then change the name of the object (remove the `temp`) and call a copy from the old object name to the new one.

In python, you can also call the move operation, it performs the copy AND the delete just after the object copy.

*Note: if you have a large number of file, it could take time (it's API call, it's slow). Think to parallelize your processing with asynchronous calls for example.*